# Expanded TextBlock property in List.View nd GridView using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I am trying to create expandable text block under every grid view column in list view. I have managed to add list resources and create C# event to collapse and expand, but I have two problems:

First is as I attach it to column expand works only on this column not entire row.

Second, I cant bind text block as as a separate row, it always shows as separate column.

Is there a way to make it so?

XAML markup:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Currents}">        
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Expandable">
            <Expander Expanded="OnChange" Collapsed="OnChange" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Details" >
            <TextBlock Text="THIS IS HIDDEN DETAILS TEST" Margin="10"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>            
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Details" Width="65" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Expandable}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MinTimestamp, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss'}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="To" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MaxTimestamp, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss'}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="File" Width="377" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SourcePaths}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Details" Width="65" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Details}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

C# code on event:

```
private void OnChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (var visible = (Visual)sender; visible != null; visible = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visible) as Visual)
    {
        if (visible.GetType() != typeof(DataGridRow)) continue;

        var row = (DataGridRow)visible;
        row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

It seems to work on data grid but now, i am missing Extendable (missing that template column with button in each row, and extending row works on row click):

```
<DockPanel>
   <Grid>
      <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Currents}">
          <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Expander Expanded="OnChange" Collapsed="OnChange" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Axm ID" Width="65" Binding="{Binding AxmId}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Channel" Width="75" Binding="{Binding SrcChannel}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="From" Width="*" Binding="{Binding MinTimestamp, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss'}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="To" Width="*" Binding="{Binding MaxTimestamp, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss'}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="File" Width="*" Binding="{Binding SourcePaths}" />
           </DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="TEST" Margin="10" />
                </DataTemplate>
           </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
       </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
 </DockPanel>
```

EDIT2:

It looks like its has something to do with MahApps.Metro

Comment: I know this is not exactly the answer to what you were asking, but have you considered the possibility to use the datagrid with the [RowDetails](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/)

Comment: Yea, it works but expanded button is missing

Comment: You mean to close the the Details section?

Comment: add a datagrid template column with a button inside and change the IsOpen (i don't recall the exact name of the property) property of the RowDetails with the click. However not that you can just open and close the RowDetails by clicking or ctrl+click on the row